# How can I merge a branch from another repo without adding the branch's full commit history?

Tags: git, merge

**Question:**

Is there a way to merge a branch from another repo, but only have the most recent commit in that branch added to our commit history?

**Background:**

We are working on a UE4 project. We try to update to the latest engine version when Epic releases an update. Our workflow is something like this:

```
dev:          a - b -- c -- d -- e -- f -- g - h - i
             /             /              /
upstream:  A (4.19) - B - C (4.20) - D - E (4.21) - F - G
```

Note that b and c represent a couple of hundred commits, and B represents usually several thousand commits. When we merge C into our repo, we "acquire" all of the commits represented by B. These extra commits add bloat to our repo, and show up interleaved with our own commits in the history view in BitBucket and in the basic `git log` output.

The last time I did the merge -- say, C in the above graph -- I did it as a squash merge, which gave me all of the changes but only made a single commit.

Unfortunately, I realized after the fact (I'm still learning git) that that effectively severed the link to upstream commits. Thus, when I went to merge E, the common base commit was A instead of C. As far as git was concerned, I had independently done the work that was in B and C in our branch. I wound up with tens of thousands of merge conflicts from files that had been modified in B & C and then further modified in D & E.

Thankfully, I was able to fairly easily recover by re-merging C, keeping the history, and then merging E.

However, I'm back to my original question. I would like to be able to merge all of the changes leading up to C into our repo but, essentially, only have C appear in our repo's commit history (to use as a common base when I go to merge E). Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Working on your project in the same repo as the engine seems a weird choice, can you not just have the engine and the code that uses it in separate repos?

Comment: Do you want to merge only the changes in the one commit or the state of the tree at that one commit?

Comment: @alexbclay - the state of the tree at that one commit

Comment: I agree with @SpoonMeiser that you should probably have different repos for development and engine code.  Any other solution is going to require a lot of git wrangling.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. We have the engine and project code together because we occasionally modify the engine to support the project. I'm not familiar with using multiple repos and keeping them in sync, but I imagine it's doable. I'll do some research in that direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: No, you can't do that.  You *can* do something that *might* suffice.

History is nothing but commits.  The commits *are* the history.

Every commit has its own unique hash ID.  That hash ID *is* the commit, in a very real sense—though technically it's a cryptographic checksum of the contents of that commit.  The contents include the hash ID of the saved source snapshot, and the hash ID of the immediately previous commit.  This is what allows Git to start at the *last* commit and work backwards, one commit at a time, through a chain of commits: commit `Z` has parent hash `Y`, so Git can find `Y` and see that it has parent hash `X`, and so on.

Merge commits are special in exactly one way: they have more than one parent hash.  (Usually they have exactly two; more than two is an *octopus merge* and these don't really achieve anything that could not have been done by multiple separate merges, though they're useful for showing that the goal of the merge was to tie a bunch of revisions together at once, and of course for showing off one's Git-fu. :-) )  At a merge commit, Git will follow *both* histories **unless you tell it not to** (see below).

As you have seen, `git merge` works by following history—the backwards-looking chain of commits—back to a shared commit.  You either have the commits, and they're shared; or you don't have them, so there is nothing to do.  Then, for normal `git merge`, it makes a merge commit, remembering both immediate predecessors, which enables future merges.  Using `git merge --squash` clips the additional parent, which—at least potentially, and often practically too—makes future merges much more difficult as you get an ancient ancestor instead of the desired modern one.

#### What you *can* do

Normally, `git log` follows the history—*all* of the history—by walking the commit graph, one step at a time, backwards:

```
...--o--o--o--o   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

When the history is linear (has no merges), this works fine, but when it has a merge:

```
          o---------o-------o
         /                   \
...--o--o                     *--o--o   <-- branch (HEAD)
         \                   /
          o--o--o--o--o--o--o
```

Git will follow *both legs of the merge* `*`, which it does one commit at a time.  But you can *tell it not to do that*:

```
git log --first-parent
```

This `--first-parent` option tells Git that when it encounters a merge commit such as `*` above, it should look only at the *first* parent of the merge.

Which parent *is* the first parent?  The answer is: the first parent of a merge is the commit that *was* the *current* commit when you *made* the merge.  So in this case, we had:

```
          o---------o-------o   <-- branch (HEAD)
         /
...--o--o
         \
          o--o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- other
```

*before* you ran `git merge`.  You had run `git checkout branch` to get into this state.  Then you ran `git merge other` to make merge commit `*`.  So the *first* parent of commit `*` is the top row commit, the one you were on when you ran `git merge`.

Thus, `git log --first-parent` won't show the bottom row of commits at all.  They will still be present, part of history, enabling future merges to work well and of course also making your repository larger, but you won't *see* them.

A great number of `git log` arguments are about *not seeing* specific commits: weeding out the trees so that you can see the forest.  For instance, `git log --simplify-by-decoration` skips showing any commits that *don't* have a branch or tag name.  Using `git log [--follow] -- <path>`, you tell Git not to show commits that *don't* change the given file or subtree.  There are further options to affect how this kind of "history simplification" works, and they get fairly complex.  You can study the `git log` manual page for days.  But start with `--first-parent`.

Comment: Awesome! I figured there were ways to filter out the upstream commits with `git log`. This doesn't help with the BitBucket history view, but definitely helps for command-line.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can get graphical views with local viewers (I've only really used `gitk` for this) and most of them should support all the history simplifier options.

Comment: This gets me thinking: is it possible to manually override the common base commit when doing a merge? Could I, for example, tell git to merge E into dev, but only the changes _after_ C (i.e. only merge D & E)?

Comment: Looks like cherry-picking a range might be an option. But we'd want to clearly document which hash we ended on for future cherry picks.

Comment: You can't do that with `git merge`, but you *can* do it manually, by merging every file yourself (e.g., `git merge-file`), the using `git write-tree` and `git commit-tree`. Git isn't designed to be used like that though. Cherry-pick is definitely not the way to go here as it's even more work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to merge a branch from another repo, but only have the most recent commit in that branch added to our commit history?

There are lots of ways to do this, but not in the full have-your-cake-and-hide-it-too sense.  This will sound awkward,sorry, but I can't find a simpler way to put it: merging histories necessarily merges the histories you merged.

So either you trim the merged history to just the commits you want, or you trim the  *display* of the merged history to just the commits you want.  Both are doable, they're even easy.

To discover how much actual repo bloat is involved here, you can make the trimmed history and compare results; as promised, it's easy:

```
git clone --bare . --single-branch --branch upstream `mktemp -d`
cd $_
```

and a simple `du -sh` gets you a reasonable baseline for how much space your upstream branch is taking in your repo.

To strip that history to just the highlights, you can

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter 's,^,sliced-,' -- upstream --simplify-by-decoration
git clone --no-hardlinks --bare . --single-branch --branch upstream `mktemp -d`
cd $_
du -sh
```

and see how much repo space that saves you.  I ran this on a Git branch, 703 tagged commits, ~55K commits.  It saved 100MB of disk space.  My screenshots directory takes more than that.  A Git checkout takes three times that.

If what's important is just de-cluttering your `git log` displays, you don't have to do any of this.  In your repo, do

```
mkdir .git/info
git rev-list upstream --parents --simplify-by-decoration >.git/info/grafts
```

and that's all you need.

Answer (score -1):

Say your upstream branch is called upstream and you want to merge it into your development branch:

```
git checkout development
git merge --squash upstream
git commit
```

This will take all the commits from the upstream branch, squash them into 1 commit, and merge it with your development branch.

Comment: Yeah, I did exactly that. But then I lose the _entire_ commit history from the upstream branch. I want to retain the most recent commit in that branch to use as a common base for future merges.